# python asyncio websockets future exception was never retrieved

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio

I'm having problems handling exceptions in tasks as I get the message:
"Future exception was never retrieved"
This seems to be only a problem for me when I'm using the websockets==8.1 package.
I'm running python 3.6.1

```
import asyncio
import websockets

class TestConnection:

    def __init__(self, market):
        self.__websocket = None

    async def connect(self, endpoint):
        self.__websocket = await websockets.connect(endpoint)

    async def on_data(self):
        async for msg in self.__websocket:
            print(msg)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
conn = TestConnection("TEST")

async def run():
    try:
        await conn.connect("wss://dstream.binance.com/ws")
        data = loop.create_task(conn.on_data())
        result = await asyncio.gather(data, return_exceptions=True)

        for r in result:
            print(f"result={r}")
    except Exception as e:
        print("handled exception")

run_task = loop.create_task(run())
loop.run_forever()
```

According to the doco, I thought that by calling gather, I would be consuming the exception.
This does not seem to be the case as I still get the exception below (if I disconnect my internet)

Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=ConnectionClosedError('code = 1006 (connection closed abnormally[internal]), no reason',)>websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: code = 1006 (connection closed abnormally [internal]), no reason
result=code = 1006 (connection closed abnormally [internal]), no reason

Oddly, if I just change the on_data function, I no longer get the "Future exception was never retrieved" issue.

```
async def on_data(self):
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    raise RuntimeError("on_data error raised")
```

Any advice on this ?